# Delegates in C++

Tags: c++, delegates

I am going through a code and I have come across the following code snippets

```
using ConnectCallback = delegate<void(Connection_ptr self)>;
using DisconnectCallback = delegate<void(Connection_ptr self, Disconnect)>;
```

I have tried to understand about delegates, but the sources were of no help.

What is the function of delegate in the above code ?

Comment: You sure that's C++? I think you may have drifted into C++-cli. Check the surrounding code for `gcnew` and declarations that look like `A ^ a;`

Comment: @user4581301 I couldn't find any of the things you have mentioned in the whole code base.

Comment: I my _self_ never seen _self_ in c++ neither.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no out-of-the-box `delegate` keyword, so with language confusion eliminated the only thing left is `delegate` being a template defined elsewhere.

`delegate` doesn't do anything in the given snippet. [It is merely an identifier that is being aliased.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) The action will occur later when the alias is used. Without the definition of `delegate` any number of things could be going on behind the scenes inside the `delegate` template, but this code snippet is  defining a pair of aliases to the `delegate` template with specific prototypes of function pointers.

Instead of having to type `delegate<void(Connection_ptr self)>` or `delegate<void(Connection_ptr self, Disconnect)>`, the programmer can use `ConnectCallback` or `DisconnectCallback` which is probably cleaner and has more meaning in context. We don't have context here, unfortunately, so I can't give a good example of usage.